# Не корректное отброжение полей в DataGridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

Работаю над приложением с использованием Entity Framework когда происходит. 
При загрузке данных из таблицы столбец ishand остаётся пустым, хотя данные в нём есть.

Я бы показал скрины но мне нужно минимум 10 балов что бы что то сюда загрузить.

Если изменяешь данные или добавляешь новые поля то таблица обновляться и столбец ishand получает нужное значение.

Я использую следующий код для инициализации
где lb переменная класса контекста
Historys список с полями из нужной таблицы
`HistorydataGridView datagridview` куда загружаются данные

```
lb.Historys.Load();
HistorydataGridView.DataSource = lb.Historys.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Классы таблиц

```
public class HistoryTabel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string book{get;set;}
    public int? isHandId { get; set; }
    public isHand ishand { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class isHand
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HistoryTabel> History { get; set; }
    public isHand()
    {
        History = new List<HistoryTabel>();

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

класс контекста

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext() : base("Library"){}

    public DbSet<BookTable> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AutorTable> Autors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MagazineTable> Magazines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HistoryTabel> Historys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<isHand> hands { get; set; }
}
```

Когда прохожу дебагером то пишет что в списке hands 0 значение.
Как решить проблему? и почему она появляется?

Comment: Нашёл решение  public isHand ishand { get; set; } не было помечено как virtual

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте свойство **ishand** виртуальным, чтобы использовать ленивую загрузку:

```
public virtual isHand ishand { get; set; }
```